# draw functions in 3D data

Tags: python

using the below code, I create three-dimensional data to plot in a `pcolormesh` plot.

```
n = 100 # size
_min, _max = -10, 10

# generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(_min, _max, n), np.linspace(_min, _max, n))

# generate z values with random noise
z = np.array([np.zeros(n) for i in range(n)])

for i in range(len(z)): 
    z[i] = z[i] + 0.1 * np.random.randint(0,3, size=len(z[i]))

# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=-1, vmax=1)

ax.set_title('pcolormesh')

plt.plot([5,5,-2.5], [5,-5,5], color='darkblue', marker='o', markersize=15, linewidth=0) # dots (outer)
plt.plot([5,5,-2.5], [5,-5,5], color='lightblue', marker='o', markersize=10, linewidth=0) # dots (inner)

plt.grid(b=True) # background grid

# set the limits of the plot to the limits of the data
ax.axis([_min, _max, _min, _max])
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

This gives an image:

[image: this]

However, I would now like to alter `z` values of specific `x`/`y` combinations according to specific functions, e.g. a circle described by `(x-5)^2 + (y+5)^2 = 1`. I would like to alter the data(!) and then plot it.

The 'goal' would be data producing an image like this:
[image]

I can experiment with the functions, it's mostly about the logic of altering the `z` values according to a mathematical function of the form `z = f(x, y)` that I cannot figure out.

It would follow the (pseudo code logic):
`if the x / y combination of a point is on the function f(x, y): add the value c to the initial z value`.

Could someone point me to how I can implement this? I tried multiple times but cannot figure it out... :( Many thanks in advance!!!

**NOTE**: an earlier version was imprecise. It wrongly explained this as a *plotting* problem although it seems that the data manipulation is the issue. Apologies for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to plot a function, the same way.

With these lines I plot a function on your plot.

```
# Create the independent points of your plot
x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# Generate your dependent variables
y = np.exp(x)

# Plot your variables
plt.plot(x, y)
```

You could then do it multiple time.

In your full example it looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100  # size
_min, _max = -10, 10

# generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(_min, _max, n), np.linspace(_min, _max, n))

# generate z values with random noise
z = np.array([np.zeros(n) for i in range(n)])

for i in range(len(z)):
    z[i] = z[i] + 0.1 * np.random.randint(0, 3, size=len(z[i]))

# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='RdBu', vmin=-1, vmax=1)

ax.set_title('pcolormesh')

plt.plot([5, 5, -2.5], [5, -5, 5], color='darkblue', marker='o', markersize=15, linewidth=0)  # dots (outer)
plt.plot([5, 5, -2.5], [5, -5, 5], color='lightblue', marker='o', markersize=10, linewidth=0)  # dots (inner)

plt.grid(b=True)  # background grid

# set the limits of the plot to the limits of the data
ax.axis([_min, _max, _min, _max])
fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax)

x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
plt.plot(x, np.exp(x))

plt.show()
```

Of course you need to change the line `y = np.exp(x)` with whatever function you need.

Comment: Thank you! I have realized that my question was wrongly focused -- the *plotting* part was wrongly emphasized! Instead, the *data manipulation* seems to be the issue (s. updated question). Your solution works well for the initial question - thank you for that! - but how would I go about manipulating the data according to a mathematical function?